# how to write text for a protobuf file which with include other protobuf

Tags: python, c++, proto

i'm new to protobuf, and i'm trying to write a `.proto` file with initial parameters parse reading from text files.

here is my test.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";
import "params_common.proto";
message TestConfig {
    required bool enable = 1 [default = true];
    required common.Common common = 2;
}
```

then, i cannot figure out how to write `test.text` files for the param `common`

the `text_format.Parse` seems like could not support input several text at once

here is `params_common.common`

```
syntax = "proto2";
package common;
message Common {
    required int element = 1 [default = 1];
}
```

thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

i figure it out

in your python code

```
fc = open('params_common.txt', 'r')
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
config = text_format.Parse(f.read()+fc.read(), test_config)
```

in `test.txt`

```
enable: true
```

in `params_common.txt`

```
common {
element : 2
}
```